# Distance between two sets

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $A,B$ be nonempty sets . $ D(A,B)=\inf\{D(a,b) : a\in  A , b \in B \} $, let $C=\operatorname{cl}(A) E=\operatorname{cl}(B)$ now how can I prove that : 
$D(A,B) = D(C,E) $

Comment: yes..this is true...

Comment: try to prove for a point and a set first...

Comment: What if $C$ and/or $E$ is empty?  (For example, if $A$ and $B$ are singletons.)

Comment: What if $A=\{\frac1n : n\in\mathbb N\}$ and $B=\{1-\frac1n : n\in\mathbb N\}$?

Comment: C contains A ( C is the set of accumulation points of A ) I mean C=Ā

Comment: What you mean should be $C$ is the closure of $A$, not the set of accumulation points of $A$.

Comment: i think he means $C=\{x\in X: \forall G(open)\ni x, G\cap A\neq \empty\}$..@CheungSW

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really mean $C = \bar{A}$ and $E = \bar{B}$, then a proof goes as follows.

Since $A \subseteq C$ and $B \subseteq E$, we have $D(A,B) \geq D(C,E)$ since the infimum of a smaller set is larger.

It suffices to show $D(A,B) \leq D(C,E)$ now.

For $\epsilon > 0$, pick $c \in C, e \in E$ s.t. $D(c, e) \leq D(C,E) + \epsilon$.

Pick $a \in A, b \in B$ s.t. $D(a, c) \leq \epsilon, D(b, e) \leq \epsilon$.

Then $D(A,B) \leq D(a, b) \leq D(a, c) + D(c, e) + D(e, b) \leq D(C,E) + 3\epsilon$

Since $\epsilon > 0$ is arbitrary, we conclude $D(A,B) \leq D(C,E)$.

Comment: why can $ \epsilon $ be omitted for being arbitrary, could you explain that part a bit please?

Answer (score 0):

Let $c \in C$ be an accumulation point of $A$ and let $e \in E$ be an accumulation point of $B$. So $B(c,r/2)\cap A\setminus\{c\}\neq \phi$ Let $x\in B(c,r)\cap A\setminus\{c\}$

Similarly,$B(e,r/2)\cap B\setminus\{e\}\neq \phi$. Let $y\in B(e,r/2)\cap B\setminus\{e\}$

Now,$d(x,y)\leq d(x,c)+d(c,y)+d(y,e)+d(e,y)<r/2+r/2+d(c,y)+d(y,e)\leq r+d(c,e)\rightarrow 1$

$D(A,B)\leq d(x,y)<r+d(c,e)$

Taking infimum on both sides $D(A,B)\leq D(C,E)+r$

Since $r$ is arbitrary ,$D(A,B)\leq D(C,E)$

On interchanging $x $ with $c$ and $y$ with $e$ in $1$ and using same arguements $D(A,B)\geq D(C,E)$